# Storing offline data from HTML form to CSV

Tags: php, javascript

I have a simple form on HTML that I want to make it work online and offline. I'm trying to post the data into a CSV file, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

**Here is my HTML code:**

```
<form>
  <label>Insert your name</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtName" />
  &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
  <input type="radio" name="choose" value="I agree with the terms and condtions">I agree with the terms and condtions
  <input type="radio" name="choose1" value="I disagree with the terms and condtions">I disagree with the terms and condtions
  <input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" onclick="check()">
  </p>
</form>
```

**and my php:**

```
if($_POST['formSubmit'] == "Submit")
{
    $errorMessage = "";
    if(empty($_POST['txtName']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Doh, You forgot to enter your name!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['choose']))
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You must agree to the terms and conditions</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['choose1'])
    {
        $errorMessage = "<li>You must agree to the terms and conditions</li>";
    }
    $varName = $_POST['txtName'];
    $varChoose = $_POST['choose'];
    $varChoose1= $_POST['choose1'];
    $fs = fopen("stelios.csv","a");
    fwrite($fs,$varName . ", " . $varChoose . "," . $varChoose1 . "\n");
    fclose($fs);
    header("Location: Test.html");
    exit;
}
```

Also, is PHP a good way for offline storage? I was thinking about the FileSystem, but it is compatible only on IE. Thanks

Comment: PHP is a *server-sided* programming language. The server-side is not there if the user is *offline*.

Comment: So is there a way to store mt data offline in a CSV file? thanks

Comment: no, because JavaScript can't write to the filesystem. You could use HTML5 localstorage instead. But thats just a key-value store, not a csv, so it can't be opened by the user

Comment: What about cookies? I know the limitations, but I was wondering if it could be a temporary solution

Comment: The FileSystem api might be able to be used. These files can't be accessed 'the normal way' either I think.

Comment: Yes, thank you. That's a solution that I was thinking. However, it is compatible only on IE. So switching to a local database would be a better solution I guess